# Revmob banner ad position - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, revmob

I have the following code to initialise and load a Revmob banner ad. I try to specify the position of the ad since it loads at the bottom by default and I need it to be at the top of the screen. This code however does not seem to work and my ad does not load. I've implemented this in my GameViewController class under viewDidLoad().

```
    let banner = RevMobBannerView()
    banner.loadAd()
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)

    let completionBlock: () -> Void = {
        banner.showAd()
        self.view.addSubview(banner)
    }

    let errorBlock: (NSError!) -> Void = {error in
        print (error);
    }

    RevMobAds.startSessionWithAppID("56b691a64756d5655fdf097e", withSuccessHandler: completionBlock, andFailHandler: errorBlock);
```

Comment: I would try to first create the frame and **then** load the add so the add will load inside the new frame. Same with adding the subview inside the completionBlock.

Comment: Sorry, could you perhaps show me this programatically?

Comment: I will post it in an aswer, I'm not sure if it will work, but I hop it does

Comment: When you don't try to change its position, does it load?

Comment: Nope, just tried that too.

Comment: On their site, they have a pretty straight-forward tutorial on how to install the adds, have you completed every step of it?

Comment: Their documentation is TRASH. I've been stuck on this too..

Answer (score 0):

I moved the .loadAd() after the frame or subview is created, maybe that helps?:

```
let banner = RevMobBannerView()
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)
    banner.loadAd()

    let completionBlock: () -> Void = {
        self.view.addSubview(banner)
        banner.showAd()
    }

    let errorBlock: (NSError!) -> Void = {error in
        print (error);
    }

    RevMobAds.startSessionWithAppID("56b691a64756d5655fdf097e", withSuccessHandler: completionBlock, andFailHandler: errorBlock);
```

Comment: Just tried it, it oddly doesn't seem to be doing anything.